# Node Lookup not returning aggregated data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, lookup

I have 2 collections in my Node App for appointments and customers, I am wanting to display the appointments and also the user associated with them. I have set up as below but I don't get the user as output.

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 firstname: String,
 surname: String,
 email: String,
});

var appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 userID: String,
 type: Number,
 time: Date
});
```

My lookup Query is like:-

```
Appointment.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"type": 1}  
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "users",
            localField: "userID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "appointmentUser"
        } 
    }
], function(err,foundAppointmentUser) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(foundAppointmentUser);
        }
    });
```

The data in mongo is here, appointment data:-

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bcc8eac7ac5980bfa365183"
    },
    "userID": "5bb4d1945480e60771ccde5a",
    "type": 1,
    "time": {
        "$date": "2018-10-22T10:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

User data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bb4d1945480e60771ccde5a"
    },
    "firstname": "Stu",
    "surname": "Test 999",
    "email": "stu@stu.com",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2018-10-03T14:26:28.815Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

And this is the result:-

```
[ { _id: 5bcc8eac7ac5980bfa365183,
    userID: '5bb4d1945480e60771ccde5a',
    type: 1,
    time: 2018-10-22T10:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 0,
    appointmentUser: [] } ]
```

Is this the best way to retrieve this type of data and also, why am I not receiving the user data under `appointmentUser` array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason for this is type difference between the `localField` and `foreignField` of the lookup.
Here, `userId` of type `String` from `appointmentSchema` is compared with the `_id` of type `ObjectId` from `userSchema` which will always return false and no record will be returned.
Change the type of `userId` in `appointmentSchema` to `ObjectId` instead of 'String'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your schema as below: FYI, [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
var appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 userID: {
   type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: 'user'
 },
 type: Number,
 time: Date
});
```

Reference Id `(UserId)` should have type `ObjectId` rather than `String`.